# monitoring changes in windows of screen while screen is detached

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

It is possible to monitor windows in screen (I mean the terminal multiplexer called screen) with Ctrl-a M. However, I am only aware of the notification when I am looking at any window. What I want, though, is to somehow also be notified if the screen in question has been detached with Ctrl-a d.

I.e., I issue the command to monitor a window in screen, then detach that screen, now I want to get a notification if the monitor detects activity, in some form (a string in the bash I'm using, or an email, or anything).

Is this possible, and if yes how?